# Checkboxes to select autogenerated methods, properties, etc

Tags: intellij-idea

In Eclipse, whenever I need to create something automatically (like delegate methods or similar), there is a checkbox beside each method thus making selection very precise and easy.

IntelliJ IDEA does not have such check boxes so we have to use CTRL or SHIFT button. Does such feature exist and how to turn it on? If not, where can we vote for it.

The main thing with IntelliJ IDEA (and the main reason people and myself like it) is the speed. In that respect, I was very surprised such way of selecting isn't the default one.

For better understanding of this issue, please look at the pic (IntelliJ IDE without check boxes).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please vote for:

- [member chooser can be more keyboard friendly](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-12937)
- [Change the way to select fields to generate constructor/getters/setters...](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-13300)

Comment: How many votes you usually need to implement a certain feature?

Comment: The fastest way to get any feature implemented is to implement it yourself and attach a patch to the issue. This functionality in available in the Community edition of IDEA and you can grab the source code from git to add checkboxes and create patch.